# Decoupling when using anonymous functions in third party javascript (FB)

Tags: javascript, oop, facebook

I'm using the FB.Event.subscribe() observer model to find out when a user logs in. This method takes two arguments, a string containing the thing to watch, and callback function.

I'm following several events that handle the event the same way, so I've set up the callback function as a pre defined method and passed this to FB.Event.subscribe() like this:

```
Controller.prototype.go = function() {
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', this.fbHandleStatusChange);
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', this.fbHandleStatusChange);
}

Controller.prototype.fbHandleStatusChange = function(response) {
    // Doesn't work
    this.otherFunction();
}

Controller.prototype.otherFunction = function() {
    alert('hello');
}
```

Unfortunately this means that I loose access to 'this' within the scope of fbHandleStatusChange, obviously I don't want to start coding references to concrete versions of Controller!

I'm guessing I'm passing the function incorrectly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, `this` is defined entirely by *how a function is called*, not where it's defined. This is different than some other languages. (JavaScript doesn't have *methods*, it just has functions and some syntactic sugar that makes them look like methods sometimes.) So although you're passing in your function correctly, Facebook doesn't know about your object instance and can't set `this` correctly when calling your function.

Check the `FB.Event.subscribe` docs to see if it offers a way to say what "context" to use to call the event handler function. It may offer a way to do that. (This will usually be a `context` or `thisArg` parameter.)

If not, you can readily solve the problem with a closure:

```
Controller.prototype.go = function() {
    var self = this;

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', handleChange);
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', handleChange);
    function handleChange() {
        return self.fbHandleStatusChange();
    }
}
```

That grabs a copy of `this` into a variable called `self`, which is used by the `handleChange` function (which is a closure over the scope containing the `self` variable) to call your function with the correct context. More about closures here: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) More about `this` here: [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Alternately, though, are you really going to have multiple instances of `Controller`? People coming to JavaScript from class-based languages tend to use constructor functions (a rough "class" analogue) unnecessarily. They're the right choice if you need to have more than one instance of an object, but if you're only ever going to have a single `Controller` object on the page, then using a constructor function and fiddling about with `this` is overkill.

**If** you don't need multiple, independent `Controller` instances, then:

```
var controllerObject = (function() {
    var inst = {};

    inst.go = go; // Make `go` a publicly-accessible function of the object
    function go() {
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', fbHandleStatusChange);
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', fbHandleStatusChange);
    }

    // This is private to us, so we don't expose it as a property on the object
    function fbHandleStatusChange(response) {
        // Doesn't work
        otherFunction();
    }

    // This is also private to us
    function otherFunction() {
        alert('hello');
    }

    return inst;
})();
```

That creates a private scope via the outer anonymous function, and within that scope creates an instance (`inst`) which we then return and refer to as `controllerObject`. `controllerObject` in the above only has one property, the function `go`. All of our other functions are truly private. (I've also taken the liberty of ensuring that the functions have *names*, because that [helps your tools help you](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html).)

Note that we don't actually refer to `inst` anywhere in our function calls, because they're all local to the closure scope. We can even have private data, by having other `var`s within the outer closure.

Comment: Just to clarify for other readers, define: var self = this, in prototype.go

Comment: @Steve: Sorry about that, I just noticed it when I was adding an explanation. :-) Glad that helped (and kudos figuring out the missing bit).

Comment: RE: new instances. I'm building up on someone else code, who used an MVC framework, so I can't take liberties like that. It's a good point though, I was using global variables as a work around, then suddenly my OOP conscience kicked in. The anonymous wrapper might be a good compromise but the code base being what it is, I think it would add additional work to iron out a few things. Again, thanks for the in-depth feedback! Will be sure to have a comprehensive read of those articles asap.

Comment: @Steve: :-) Just presenting alternatives, whether it's the right thing varies depending on circumstances.